# Addressing a teacher properly

Tags: word-choice, forms-of-address

How can I address a teacher when I don't know his or her name? Can I say "excuse me sir" or "excuse me teacher"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer depends entirely upon the local custom in a questioner's culture and community.

Comment: "Hey, teacher!" quote by Roger Waters (Pink Floyd)

Comment: Is it your teacher? Years ago I used to work on trade shows, and I addressed teachers with either "Go away" or "Not another teacher...".

Answer (score 1):

Usually,

> **teacher**

is sufficient to address an instructor in most situations, though custom may vary by culture.

For example,

> **sensei**, or 先生

is usually translated to mean "teacher" but has additional context in Asian cultures.

In a western culture university setting

> **Professor** *surname*

is usually appropriate.